# The instance of entity type 'Ticket' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando cambiar la propiedad Estado de una instancia de la entidad Ticket, por lo que desde la base de datos extraigo el ticket, busco el estado, y asigno ticket.Estado = Estado. Pero cada vez que se cambia el estado de un ticket, también se debe crear una nueva instancia de Bitacora. Ticket tiene un HashTable<Bitacora_Ticket>, y esta nueva instancia de Bitacora_Ticket se crea llamando al método crearNuevaBitacora(), la cual devuelve una nueva instancia de Bitacora_Ticket, la cual luego se añade al HashTable<Bitacora_Ticket>.
Luego todos estos cambios se deben de reflejar en la base de datos, y procedo a añadir la nueva instancia de Bitacora_Ticket a la tabla Bitacora_Ticket, e intento además actualizar el campo de Estado del Ticket en la base de datos.

```
public void modificarEstadoTicket(Guid ticketId, Guid estadoId)
        {
            TicketValidaciones ticketValidaciones = new TicketValidaciones(_dataContext);
            ticketValidaciones.validarTicket(ticketId);
            TicketDTO ticket = _mapper.Map<TicketDTO>(_dataContext.Tickets.Where(tickets => tickets.Id == ticketId).Single());
            Estado nuevoEstado = _dataContext.Estados.Where(estados => estados.Id == estadoId).Single();
            ticket.Estado = nuevoEstado;
            ticket.Bitacora_Tickets.Add(crearNuevaBitacora(ticket));
            _dataContext.Bitacora_Tickets.Add(ticket.Bitacora_Tickets.First());
            _dataContext.Tickets.Update(_mapper.Map<Ticket>(ticket));
            _dataContext.DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Pero cuando intento hacer eso, en el momento de guardar Bitacora_Ticket en la base de datos, me sale el error que dice el título de la pregunta. No se por que pasa esto.

Comment: en el metodo crearNuevaBitacora de casualidad haces algo como Bitacora_Tickets.Ticket = ticket ?

Comment: @StialManstike sí

Comment: te dejo en una respuesta mi teoria de que esta pasando, pensaba ponerlo aqui pero me sobre explique, espero te ayude en algo.

Comment: @StialManstike  Muchas gracias, una pregunta, si Ticket guarda un HashTable de Bitacora_Ticket (HashTable<Bitacora_Ticket>), para recuperar luego la lista de bitacoras perteneciente a un solo ticket, basta con hacer el Include(t=>t.Bitacora_Ticket) o mejor busco las Bitacoras mediante el Id del Ticket?

Comment: Es correcto, cualquiera de las dos funcionaria, por relacion deberia de traer la lista de Bitacora_Tickets al hacer include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework hace un track de todas las entidades, lo que le permite "guardar por referencia", cuando asignas `Bitacora_Tickets.Ticket = ticket` este va a tratar de guardar o crear el `Ticket` por referencia en la BD y previamente tu agregaste a `ticket.Bitacora_Tickets` una nueva instancia por medio de `ticket.Bitacora_Tickets.Add()`, a la cual le estas asignando el `ticket` por medio de `Bitacora_Ticket.Ticket`, no se si me doy a explicar, pero estas haciendo un tipo de referencia circular en las entidades que se encuentran editando.

No necesitas hacer el `_dataContext.Bitacora_Tickets.Add()` porque se va a guardar por medio de la entidad de `Ticket`, de hecho creo que esta de mas el automapper.

Yo lo que haria,seria traer la entidad, asignarle el estado, crearle la bitacora, y guardar. mas o menos asi:

```
Ticket ticket = _dataContext.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(tickets => tickets.Id == ticketId);
ticket.EstadoId = estadoId; 
ticket.Bitacora_Tickets.Add(new Bitacora_Ticket(){ // solo como ejemplo, desconosco los campos
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
     ... // No hace falta asignar el ticketId ni nada por el estilo porque se guardara por referencia
}); 
_dataContext.Tickets.Update(ticket);
_dataContext.DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

cuando se haga el guardado, entity Framework detectara que la entidad Bitacora_Ticket es nueva y la guardara automaticamente.

---

Tambien puedes simplemente en tu metodo `crearNuevaBitacora` no asignar el `Bitacora_Tickets.Ticket` y no hacer el

```
_dataContext.Bitacora_Tickets.Add(ticket.Bitacora_Tickets.First());
```

Espero haberme explicado, saludos.